# AngularJS temlateUrl broken in component after Refactor ->Move in WebStorm

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, refactoring, webstorm, angularjs-components

I am using WebStorm to do component-based AngularJS development.

As we are having multiple modules used to assemble multiple application variants it happens quite often that I am moving an angular component along with its template to a different folder in the project structure using WebStorm's Refactor -> Move functionality.

Whenever I do that the path to the template in a components `templateUrl` property gets refactored from

```
templateUrl: 'path/to/my/component/my-template.html'
```

to

```
templateUrl: 'my-template.html'
```

Can I somehow tell WebStorm to use the same reference point (basically the app folder) for the path refactoring? So that it becomes

```
templateUrl: 'path/to/my/new-component/my-template.html'
```

instead?

Answer (score 0):

no, not possible:( Please vote for [WEB-13707](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13707) and linked ticket to be notified on any progress